# Converting a Microsoft access SQL query using Ccur to SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, ms-access

Trying to convert this SQL statement from Microsoft access to SQL server. I understand that SQL Server doesnt use Ccur do they use CONVERT instead?

```
SELECT 
Ccur(Choose(IIF(IsNull(SCStatus),1
,IIF(SCStatus=0,1,2))
,IIF(IsNull(TaxTDThisEmt),0
,TaxTDThisEmt)
,IIF(IsNull(SCTaxYTD),0
,SCTaxYTD))) AS [Tax This Employment]
FROM EeBals
```

Comment: Which version of SQLServer do want to use? 2008 and newer, or older than 2008 ?

Comment: @reporter 2012 I am using

Comment: Maybe you look for the cast command to convert the number or string into datatype `money`and `smallmoney`.

Comment: @OverMind that won't work because of the ISNULL function requires 2 arguements

Comment: @user3734454 http://www.techrepublic.com/article/learn-the-differences-between-is-null-and-isnull-in-access/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you close:

```
SELECT 
    CAST(
            (
                 CASE WHEN ISNULL(SCStatus, 0) = 0 THEN ISNULL(TaxTDThisEmt, 0)
                 ELSE ISNULL(SCTaxYTD, 0) 
                 END
            ) as money
    ) as [Tax This Employment] 
FROM Table
```